# Web service running time is slow and causing slow running web page

Tags: php, performance, soap, time, loading

I"m using below third party code to send SMS for customers who are making orders in my web store, it seems this code is loading slowly and it's causing my order confirmation page (which has this code inside) to load slow.

is there any solution that I can use this code but it's slowness don't affect my page ?

Thanks

```
// Send SMS
/*
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://87.107.121.54:2620/post/send.asmx', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

$parameters['username'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$parameters['password'] = "xxxx";
$parameters['to'] = "$phone";
$parameters['from'] = "1000947320";
$parameters['text'] ="test";
$parameters['isflash'] =false;

$sms_client->SendSimpleSMS2($parameters)->SendSimpleSMS2Result;

*/
```

Comment: Did you check if it's **YOUR** code cause the problem, or just that your server's link to the API server is itself slow? If it's your server, then you should work on figuring out why it's slow. If it's the soap request, then you should get a better server or API provider, which have better/faster links.

Answer (score 0):

Make the confirmation page add the values into database and create a script which processes the values from the database, meaning:
when user enters the page, your code will do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sms SET to='$to', text='$text', sent=0;
```

and then you make a script which does the following:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$parameters['username'] = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$parameters['password'] = "xxxx";
$parameters['from'] = "1000947320";
$parameters['isflash'] =false;

$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://87.107.121.54:2620/post/send.asmx', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent=0");
while( $message = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $thisMessage = $parameters;
    $thisMessage['to'] = $message['to'];
    $thisMessage['text'] = $message['text'];

    $sms_client->SendSimpleSMS2($thisMessage)->SendSimpleSMS2Result;

    mysql_query('UPDATE sms SET sent=1 WHERE id='.$message['id']);
}
```

and you run this script in cron, lets say every minute or how often do you want to.

Comment: Nice idea :) appreciate it!

Comment: This will cause the sms to have a bit of a "lag", since it wont be sent at the moment user enters the confirmation page, but speeds up the confirmation page loading for user. Hopefully you got the idea and if this helps, I'd appreciate to get a vote :)